# Why does the Protobuf JavaScript compiler suffix collections with "List", "Map", etc?

Tags: javascript, protocol-buffers, grpc-gateway

Why does the protobuf JavaScript code generator suffix collections with the collection type?

For example:

- `repeated string names` becomes `obj.namesList`
- `map<string, string> bar` becomes `obj.barMap`

And this is as per the documentation, here: https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers/docs/reference/javascript-generated#repeated

Why is that?

It makes life difficult when using `grpc-gateway` with `--swagger_out` because the swagger API definitions don't match the generated JavaScript.

Comment: Did you find any method to instruct compiler to suppress adding suffix?

Comment: There's a feature request to enable/disable this feature - https://github.com/protocolbuffers/protobuf/issues/6773